# AJAX error not returning jqXHR.responseText.modelState when using custom dll

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I am using an asp.net webapi controller, and in my project I have a dll that I built myself.  The dll is being used to validate if the person that the user is typing in actually exists.

Here is my controller method:

```
// POST: api/EventsAPI
[ResponseType(typeof(Event))]
public IHttpActionResult PostEvent(Event @event)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (@event.DateEndOfEvent < @event.DateOfEvent) // successfully returns error.modelState (in view code)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("DateEndOfEvent", "End Date Cannot Be Before Start Date!");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (!EmpData.IsValid(@event.PersonWorkedOne)) // returns error.modelState as undefined (in view code)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("PersonWorkedOne", "This person does not exist!");
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@event.PersonWorkedTwo))
    {
        if (!EmpData.IsValid(@event.PersonWorkedTwo)) // returns error.modelState as undefined (in view code)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("PersonWorkedTwo", "This persondoes not exist!");
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }
    }

    db.Event.Add(@event);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = @event.Id }, @event);
}
```

Now the two conditional statements above that have `EmpData`.. `EmpData` is from my dll.

Here is the ajax code in my view:

```
$("form").data("validator").settings.submitHandler =
    function(form) {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: infoGetUrl,
            data: $("form").serialize(),
            success: function() {
                toastr.options = {
                    onHidden: function () {
                        window.location.href = newUrl;
                    },
                    timeOut: 3000
                }
                toastr.success("Event successfully created.");
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                var error = $.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText);

                var modelState = error.modelState;
                console.log(modelState);
                $.each(modelState,
                    function (key, value) {
                        var id = "";
                        if (key === "$id") {
                            id = "#" +
                                key.replace('$', '').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                                key.substr(2);
                        } else {
                            id = "#" +
                                key.replace('$', '').substr(0, 1).toUpperCase() +
                                key.substr(1);
                            var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
                            console.log(key);

                            toastr.error(status + " - " + modelState[key]);
                        }
                        var input = $(id);
                        console.log(id); // result is #id
                        if (input) { // if element exists
                            input.addClass('input-validation-error');
                        }
                    });
            }
        });
    }
```

Now, in the controller when I purposefully test to get the error message concering the end date being before the start date, I receive `error.modelState`.  But when I purposefully test to get the error message saying that a person does not exist... I do not get `error.modelState`.. that returns as `undefined`.

Does returning ModelState not work when using custom DLL?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: why do you return a response within each validation check? That way the caller can only find out, tediously, one-by-one, which fields are invalid. It would be more caller-friendly to add to the modelstate within each `if` statement, then also set ModelState.IsValid false inside them and only return BadRequest at the end of the validation process, if ModelState.IsValid is false (i.e. there's at least one error). Then if multiple fields are invalid, the caller will see them all at once.

Comment: It'll also allow a more sophisticated test of your issue, whereby we can send invalid data for both the event _and_ person fields, and see if you still get a modelstate back. There's no reason I can think of why calling code in a library would cause the modelstate not to appear. A more likely explanation is that EmpData.IsValid is returning true when it shouldn't, and your call is failing for another reason, which doesn't return a modelState. You'll only get a modelState if a) the HTTP status is 400 and b) you actually send a modelState in the response.

Comment: When you do your test of an invalid person, is the HTTP response code you get back definitely 400? And have you stepped through the code to verify that it does actually enter the `if (!EmpData.IsValid(@event.PersonWorkedOne))` or `if (!EmpData.IsValid(@event.PersonWorkedTwo))` blocks, and definitely returns the lines within? If so, pause on the `return` statement and check the value of modelState on the server-side at that moment - is it what you expect? And have you checked your network tab in the browser to examine the actual response, not just the output from jQuery?

Comment: In short, you need to provide some more detailed debugging information, because the cause you're attributing the problem to is a very implausible one. All you're doing is calling some library code. The fact that a method you call in one statement is in a library cannot, in itself, have any material impact on the code that follows it. The only impact it can have is if the method has a bug in it, causing the calling code not to behave the way you intended.

Comment: @ADyson okay just checked, and it does not enter the `if` blocks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to figure this out with the help of ADyson.  I edited my DLL file to return just a bool object.

Originally if what I was checking in `IsValid` was anything other than true, then I would throw an exception which was causing this error.

So taking the exception part out and just returning either true or false worked.

**Original**

```
public static bool IsValid(string person)
{
    bool empExists = lstAllEmps.Any(x => x.IDNumber == person);

    if (empExists)
    {
        return empExists;
    }
    else
    {
        var exceptionMessage = string.Format("The person, {0}, does not exist!", person);
        throw new ArgumentException(exceptionMessage, person);
    }
}
```

**New**

```
public static bool IsValid(string person)
{
    bool empExists = lstAllEmps.Any(x => x.IDNum == person);


    return empExists;
}
```

Comment: yep, throwing an exception would do it, because the normal flow of execution would cease, and the server would probably just return a 500 Internal Server Error. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: You should realize that since this is the "correct" answer your question is offtopic since we'd have never been able to figure out that you were throwing an exception. Next time, please follow the [MCVE] guideline.